# Why does the pion half-life differ between the charged and uncharged species?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, conservation-laws, weak-interaction, pions

Why does the uncharged pion have much shorter half-life than the charged pion despite the fact that the uncharged pion has a little bit less mass than the charged one, so that according to the uncertainty principle we should expect the uncharged pion to decay at a little bit slower rate when compared to the charged pion?

Comment: For the uncertainty principle part of the question (v4), see also [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53428/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point is that the quark and the antiquark inside a charged [meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson) must necessarily have different [flavors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_%28particle_physics%29) so the decay cannot be via the flavor-preserving electromagnetic interaction, but must wait for the [weak interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction). In contrast, the decay of a neutral [pion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) needs no flavor change and can use the much faster electromagnetic interaction.